# Using Orchard CMS, how do I add a script reference for display only on the home page?

Tags: orchardcms

I have a site that is using Orchard CMS and I would like to add a script reference and bit of JavaScript to the home page. It needs to be placed below the existing jQuery script include.  What's the best way to achieve this?  I've tried using an HTML Widget in the Footer zone of TheHomePage layer of my theme, but this widget produces a  and doesn't place the element in the correct location (at the bottom of the  element, below the existing jquery reference).

The site is running an **old** version of Orchard; 1.0 I believe.

Comment: It's actually running v1.3.10, so maybe some of these answers will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a layout alternate for the homepage (but that may not exist on an antique 1.0), layout-homepage.cshtml with a `@using(Script.Foot()) {}` block containing your script, or you can use Vandelay Classy to add a script from the admin (but that probably also won't work on 1.0).

Comment: Bertrand - Any recommendations for someone who can (inexpensively) upgrade an Orchard site to the latest version? Feel free to email steve AT kentsmiths.com

Answer (score 0):

Or if none of what Bertrand mentioned above work, just add a html widget to the homepage layer and chuck your script reference in the html section